# Openlayers-workshop on Windows - ol not defined

Tags: openlayers-3

Trying to go through the "openlayers-workshop" on Windows 8. In the "Basic - Creating a Map" section following the instructions and making the example map.html file. When viewing the html file in my browser the following error occurs:

ReferenceError: ol is not defined 
Sourcefile: http://localhost:4000/map.html
Line: 18

I have followed the tutorial as far and installed the required prerequisites.

Is there something I haven't installed yet to make it work?

Any other Windows users out there that have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://openlayers.org/download/ and download latest *dist.zip file. Extract this file. In the extracted folder there will be 3 files, you only need ol.js and ol.css. In the directory you have map.html create 2 folders, one called "css" and another called "js". In the "css" folder placer the ol.css file from the extracted folder. In the "js" folder placer the ol.js file from the extracted folder. In your map.html file change the line on line 4(may be different, you should see a line),

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

Change this to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

Similarly on line 12 of the map.html file change

```
 <script src="/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To

```
 <script src="js/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now save and reload the map.html file, now it should display correctly. The reason you where original getting a error was because you hadn't included the openlayers library in your map.html file correctly.